# Can't access file in directory outside of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Hi I have a a standard wordpress installation on my server, I have added a etc folder in the root i.e. this is how it looks :

```
etc
wp-admin
wp-content
index.php
.htaccess
```

The .htaacess look like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I try to access a php script inside the "etc" folder I get "No such file or directory" error. I assume this is down to the .htaccess file. What do I need to add to the. .htaaccess to allow etc folder scripts to be accessed ?

Comment: Show us the code so we can see HOW you attempt to access the `etc` directory

Comment: Those RewriteConds checking on %{REQUEST_FILENAME} make the following rule apply only, if the request did not match any physically existing file or folder. So if by _"try to access a php script inside the "etc" folder"_ you mean a script file that actually exists, this should _not_ be caused by the .htaccess in the first place.

Comment: the file inside the etc folder right now is just test.php and contains 

<php
 echo "all good";
?>

It's accessed via a cronjob

Comment: Actually I just removed the .htaccess file altogether and I still get "No such file or directory" error .. now I'm baffled !